# Extracting substring from environment variable

Tags: shell-script, string, variable, url

In a bash or zsh script, how might I extract the
host from a url, e.g. `unix.stackexchange.com` from
`http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`, if the latter is in an environment variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion, which is available in any POSIX compliant shell.

```
$ export FOO=http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
$ tmp="${FOO#*//}" # remove http://
$ echo "${tmp%%/*}" # remove everything after the first /
unix.stackexchange.com
```

A more reliable, but uglier method would be to use an actual URL parser. Here is an example for `python`:

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys; from urllib.parse import urlparse; print(urlparse(sys.argv[1]).netloc)' "$FOO"
unix.stackexchange.com
```

Answer (score 5):

If the URLs all follow this pattern I have this short and ugly hack for you:

```
echo "$FOO" | cut -d / -f 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it many ways, some of them being:

```
export _URL='http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask'

echo "$_URL" | sed -ne 'y|/|\n|;s/.*\n\n/;P'

expr "$_URL" : 'http://\([^/]*\)'

echo "$_URL" |  perl -lpe '($_) = m|^http://\K[^/]+|g'

perl -le 'print+(split m{/}, $ENV{_URL})[2]'

(set -f; IFS=/; set -- $_URL; echo "$3";)
```

Comment: Nice alternatives. +1. Though the sed solution has a small mistake; one slash is missing. should be `echo "$_URL" | sed -ne 'y|/|\n|;s/.*\n\n//;P'` or even better `echo "$_URL" | sed -ne 'y|/|\n|;s|.*\n\n||;P'`

Answer (score 2):

Can be done also with regex groups:

```
$ a="http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask"
$ perl -pe 's|(.*//)(.*?)(/.*)|\2|' <<<"$a"
unix.stackexchange.com
```